# LEd is not compiling

Tags: errors, pdftex, compiling, editors

After 4 years I decided to take up again LEd, which I used for my bachelor thesis. It was alright until I decided to compile to see the PDF. The error was:

> 21-07-2015 08:27:48: START /b/c1/c"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\LEd\Batches\pdflatex.bat" "C:\Users\Davide Daino
>   Raghnar\Desktop\tesi" "prima_versione_tesi.tex" C: "pdflatex.exe" non
>   Š riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno, un programma eseguibile
>   o un file batch.

Now, I don't know what this is. I searched online for something and I found that it could be some file not being installed properly.

I uninstalled all and reinstalled again. Nothing changed. I thought also that could be the `.tex` file written in the wrong folder. I did not want to move anything to avoid creating even more confusion.

But now the problem is: I don't know how to compile it. Any idea?

Now, after another day, is compiling.
I don't know why.
I'm using texlive 2015 and an editor (I don't remember the name, was something like windedit or similar)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE . It seems that you have a problem with pdflatex which is missing. What are your IDE and it's version?

Comment: Don't take up LEd. That project has deprecated and the editor is quite buggy though I wish they continued because it had really nice ideas implemented. There are much more recent and advanced editors out there for each OS.

Comment: I don't know how to find the information about IDE. Can you help me?

Comment: Another Editor? Like? Ideas?

Comment: just install a latex distribution like texlive or miktex

Comment: There are a bunch of editors out there, see [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339) TeXworks (included in TeX Live and MikTeX) is nice and simple. TeXmaker and TeXStudio are quite popular, and has more features. One note about this site: to make sure people are notified of comments, write `@<username>` in the comment, see [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019).

Comment: If you are on Windows, I think TeXnicCenter is arguably the editor for the average user. Though anything else is also useful but TeXnicCenter is pretty good at auto-configuration for the less involved users..

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Since the user is on Windows... But to avoid confusion, TeXworks is not included in TeX Live *generally*. I guess it is added to the Windows edition. Not sure about MacTeX currently.

Comment: @percusse gas it gotten better with its suggestions? Last time I tested it I did not find it user friendly that if I typed `\begin{doc` then it asked if I wanted to insert `\begin{document} `,  sure and I ended up with `\begin{\begin{document} `.  Not nice. And these days does it come with a build in off viewer or do one still have to set that up manually?

Comment: @daleif You have to write doc and then ctrl+space

Comment: Exactly, that is not intuitive for a new user. There I like the texmaker/texstudio equivalent better

Comment: @daleif That's a known bug and in the issue tracker. But the general rule is if it is a control sequence you type \doc and it completes to \documentclass if it is an environment you just write the name of the environment because the idea is to type less. I surely don't want to type \begin which is pointless for auto-completion. So I like TeXnicCenter way better.

Answer (score 7):

Don't take up LEd. That project has deprecated long time ago and the editor is quite buggy though I wish they continued. Because it had really nice ideas implemented as beta. There are much more recent and advanced editors out there for each OS and LEd is just a historical artifact.